# Logging from two simultaneous processes

Tags: java, unix, logging, operating-system, multiprocessing

I have written an application in java and deployed it on a unix server.
I have implemented the logging in my app and the logs are generated in a file say `X.log.txt`

If I run multiple instances of my jar using different users or single user different sessions: 
Is there a chance that my logs in `X.log.txt` get mixed?

 or it will be in FCFS manner??

---

Example: let P1 and P2 be two processes that are calling the java app and are generating logs.

P1 and P2 ARE writing their individual logs at the same time to `X.log.txt`.  Is this statement true?  Or is it entirely based on the CPU scheduling algorithm (FCFS, SJF, etc.)?

Even if i don't use the timestamping Its working fine for me.
When I am executing them the logs are generated one after the other , Means For a particular instance all the logs are written into the file and then for the next instance. My question is still open is it all based on the way our processor is written to handle jobs or is it some thing else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two processes are writing to same log file, data will get randomly corrupted. You will get lines cut in the middle and finishing with data from other log. You can even end up with good chunks of binary zeroes in various places of the file, depending on OS (and in some OSes, it will just fail to write to same file from two places at same time).

Write to separate files and then join/browse them using some 3rd party tools to get timestamp-ordered view.

Comment: Or log by sending to a logging process that accepts complete log messages  from multiple sources, and writes them to a single log-file.  (Like `syslog`, since the OP is on a Unix system).

Answer (score 0):

If both your processes are writting to the same directory and file path you will get some odd behaviour. Depending on your implementation both applications will write to the file at the same time or one application will block the other from writing at all.

My suggestion would be to generate the log file's name at runtime and append something unique like a timestamp or a pid (process id) so there's no more conflict:

`X.log.[PID].txt` or `X.log.[TIMESTAMP].txt`

NOTE: You'll have to use a low enough resolution in the timestamp (seconds or nanoseconds) to avoid a name collision.